# Python: Get each element from a list based on position, brackets, and parentheses

Tags: python

So I have the next list:

```
a = ["[Test](Link)", "[Test2](link2)", "[test3](link3)"]
```

And I want to get it to show in this way:

```
b1 = Test
b2 = Link
b3 = test3
b4 = link2
b5 = test3
b6 = link3
```

How could I do something like this?

I've tried to join the list and use re to get what I want but I failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = ["[Test](Link)", "[Test2](link2)", "[test3](link3)"]
>>> b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6 = (y.strip('[]()') for x in a for y in x.split(']'))
>>> print (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6)
Test Link Test2 link2 test3 link3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = ["[Test](Link)", "[Test2](link2)", "[test3](link3)"]
for s in a:
    m = re.match('(\[.*\])(\(.*\))$', s)
    print(m.group(1))
    print(m.group(2))
```

results:

```
[Test]
(Link)
[Test2]
(link2)
[test3]
(link3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`re.findall`** after using **`join`** on your list:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\[.*?\]|\(.*?\))', ''.join(a))
['[Test]', '(Link)', '[Test2]', '(link2)', '[test3]', '(link3)']
```

Regex Explanation:

```
(                       # Matching group 1
    \[.*?\]             # Matches non-greedily in between brackets
    |                   # OR
    \(.*?\)             # Matches non-greedily between parenthesis
)                       # End of matching group
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original question looks like you want each value to be representing by a new variable. You can use `globals()` to dynamically create new variables.

```
count = 0
g = globals()
for i in a:
     f = i.strip('[)').split('](')
     count += 1
     g['b' +  str(count)] = f[0]
     print ('b' + str(count) + ' = ' + f[0])
     count += 1
     g['b' + str(count)] = f[1]
     print ('b' + str(count) + ' = ' + f[1])


b1 = Test
b2 = Link
b3 = Test2
b4 = link2
b5 = test3
b6 = link3
```

Below is the output of the variables that were dynamically created.

```
In [5]: b1
Out[5]: 'Test'

In [6]: b2
Out[6]: 'Link'

In [7]: b3
Out[7]: 'Test2'

In [8]: b4
Out[8]: 'link2'

In [9]: b5
Out[9]: 'test3'

In [10]: b6
Out[10]: 'link3'
```